# Tensorflow 2.x: Create tensor with None dimension and final dimension of one

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I have a tensor of shape `[None, n_steps, n_filt]` to which I need to concatenate a new "scalar" feature (call it `x`).  It has dimension of `[None, 1]`.  This scalar should be appended as a new feature value, adding the same constant value for every step and generating a new tensor of shape `[None, n_steps, n_filt+1]`.  Ideally, I would just create a new tensor and concatenate the new one to it:

```
new_feat = tf.ones([None, n_steps, 1]) * x 
tf.concat([orig_tensor, new_feat], axis=2)
```

But I can't create a tensor with a None shape.  I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

After much fiddling, I discovered the `ones_like()` method, which copies the shape of the original tensor.  But I need to reduce the last dimension to one and using a slice destroys that dimension.  I can recreate it, but its a mess.
I built the following line, which does what I want but which seems needlessly verbose.  Is there a better way to do this:

```
new_feat = tf.expand_dims(tf.ones_like(orig_tensor)[:,:,0],axis=-1)*x
tf.concat([orig_tensor, new_feat], axis=2)
```

EDIT: Even though the above code compiles, it does not run.  Sigh.

```
Incompatible shapes: [1000,156,1] vs. [1000,1]
```

EDIT 2:  Here is another try at it.  Starting with the original feature with dimension = [None, 1], using `expand_dim()` to insert a new dimension and then use `gather()` to replicate the middle dimension:

```
tf.gather(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1), indices=[0]*n_steps, axis=1)
```

EDIT 3: Here is another option:

```
tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(x, axis=1), multiples=[1,n_steps,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

In simplest way you could define two input layers and then concatenate them together:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

n_steps = 3
n_filt = 5
input_0 = tf.keras.layers.Input((n_steps, n_filt))
input_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((n_steps, ))
new_feat = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((n_steps, 1))(input_1)
cat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input_0, new_feat])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_0, input_1], outputs=cat)
model.summary()

batch_size = 2
scalar_value = 1
inp_0 = np.random.rand(batch_size, n_steps, n_filt)
inp_1 = np.full((batch_size, n_steps), scalar_value)
out_cat  = model([inp_0, inp_1])
print(out_cat)
```

Comment: @"Mr. For Example" I've spent sometime working through your code and expanding on it.  First, the input tensor `input_1` needs to have dimension `[None, 1]`.  With your code with input is `[None, n_steps]`, and in that case a simple reshape will indeed solve the problem.  But with `[None, 1]` the scalar needs to be repeated out with `n_step` copies along a newly inserted axis=1.  I dug through the API more and discovered the `tf.tile()` which can function similarly to `tf.gather()` and distribute copies along a chosen dimension.  Thank you for your response.